# mean independence of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2...$ is said to be mean independent if $E[X_k∣X_1,...,X_{k-1}]=E(X_k)$ for all $k$.

So if we change the order, this property remains true? for example $E[X_1∣X_2,...,X_{k}]=E(X_1)$.

Thanks

Comment: I think that the first assertion is true. It is about the mean independence of a sequence of random variables, and this is the definition that I found in books !!

Comment: apparently, I missed the word "mean" -- eventhough I read it twice, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No. For a simple counter-example consider $\{X^{2},X,0,0,\cdots\}$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: But using your counter-example we have: $E[X_2/ X_1]= E[X_2/ X_2]= X_2$ but by definition we have $E[X_2/ X_1]= E(X_2)$. Then, $E(X_1)= E(X_2) = X_2 = X_1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not remain true if we change the order.

Let $(Y_n)$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(Y_n=2)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0)=\frac 12$, and define a martingale $(M_n)$ by $M_0 = 1$, $M_n = \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$.  Let $X_n := M_n-M_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 1$.  By the martingale property, $\mathbb{E}[X_n|X_1,...,X_{n-1}] = 0=\mathbb{E}[X_n]$.  However, since $M_1 = 0$ implies $M_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$, we know that $\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2,...,X_n]$ is $1$ on the event $X_2 \ne 0$.  Therefore, we conclude $\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2,...,X_n] \ne 0$.